# ReactJS: How to create a self-validating input field?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dom-events

I have a form where one of the fields needs a very specific validation. I want to be able to reuse this fields in other forms without the form having to re-implement the validation method again and again.

I thought extracting the input field to its own component, `DomainInput` would work:

```
<div id="domain-input-area" class={this.state.showDomain ? '' : 'base-remove'}>
     <DomainInput/>
</div>
```

`DomainInput` then contains all the validation logic for itself

```
import { Component } from 'react';
//import '../../../login-box/login-box.styles.css'
import '../domain-input/domain-input.styles.css';

class DomainInput extends Component{

  constructor(){
    super();

    this.state = {
        domain:'',
        valid:false,
        error:''
    };
  }

  handleDomainInput = (e) => {

    let domain = e.target.value;
    let error = '';
    let valid = true;
  
    if(domain.indexOf('my.salesforce.com') === -1){
        error = `${this.state.domain} is not a valid salesforce domain`;
        valid = false;
        this.setState({error:error,valid:valid});
        
    }
  
    if(domain.indexOf('https://') != 0){
        error = `Please use https://`;
        valid = false;
        this.setState({error:error,valid:valid});;
        
    }

    if(valid){
        domain = domain.trim();
        let lastCharacter = domain.substr(domain.length-1);
        
        //remove last slash
        if(lastCharacter === '/'){
        domain = domain.substr(0,domain.length-1);
        }
    
        this.setState({domain:domain,valid:true});
    }
  }

  render(){
      return (
        <input type="text" placeholder="https://your-domain.my.salesforce.com" class={this.state.valid ? 'base-input valid' : 'base-input invalid'} id="domain-input"  onChange={this.handleDomainInput}/>
      )
  }
}

export default DomainInput
```

My idea was that when `DomainInput` knew that its state was valid, it would fire an event to the parent component (the form) to let it know that it has been validated.

But I realised this is not the react way due to one-way data flow, and instead the `onChange` handler should be implemented in the parent, which as I said, I don't want to do because I want to be able to drop `DomainInput` in any form, and have it validate itself.

Other frameworks like [LWC](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/lwc.events_create_dispatch) allow child components to send custom events to the parent. In my case, it would send a `validated` event and this would in turn set the parent's state to `validDomain:true`

How do I do this the react way?

Answer (score 1):

To give you an idea, how you can do with parent (manages state) and child (Custom Input Field), Here's sample code:

**TextField.jsx**

```
export const TextField = ({error, ...rest}) => {
  return (
    <div className="mb-6">
      <label htmlFor={rest.name} className="">
        {rest.label}
      </label>
      <input
        type="text"
        {...rest}
        className={ '' + (!!error ? ' border-red' : '')}
      />
      {error && <div className="...">{error}</div>}
    </div>
  )
}
```

**ParentComponent.jsx**

```
 this.state = { email: '', error: '' }

 <TextField
        label="Email Address"
        name="email"
        value={this.state.email}
        placeholder="doge@example.com"
        onChange={handleChange}
        onBlur={handleBlur}
        error={state.error}
      />
```

Now validate your input and set the state accordingly in the parent component using custom **handleChange** and **handleBlur** functions as follow:

```
handleChange = (event) => {
    let { name, value } = event.target
    // set state here and also validate
}

handleBlur = (event) => {
  let { name, value } = event.target
  // set state here and also validate
}
```

Comment: But isn't this exactly what I'm trying to avoid? The handleChange is implemented in the parent component. If I want to reuse DomainInput across multiple forms, how can I make the validation happen directly inside DomainInput? Otherwise every form would have to implement a handler and pass it down to DomainInput

Comment: If you're going to use for multiple places, you can make generic validator which invokes inside onBlur or onChange. What would I suggest to here again, you should check Formik - highly recommended library to validate forms.